# AngularJS forEach function - cannot get to resolve to true

Tags: angularjs, controller, ng-show

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    $scope.checkSchedule = function (value) {
        var result = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.shifts, function (obj) {

            if (obj['PublishedEmployee.Id'] === value && result === false) {
                result = true;
            }

        });
        return result;
    };
```

My `$scope.shifts` is an array of objects. Each object contains another object, `PublishedEmployee` and that object has a property of `Id`.

My goal is to iterate over the $scope.shifts objects and if the `PublishedEmployee.Id` property == `$scope.currentId` then resolve the function to be `true`.

In my HTML I have the following:

`ng-show="checkSchedule(currentId)"`

So, if the function resolves to true, the element will display. However, I'm always receiving `false`, what am I missing to have this resolve accordingly?

Pictures:

[image: PublishedEmployee.Id]

[image: currentId]

Comment: Are you sure the condition actual becomes true at some point in time? I don't see any debugging in place to confirm that.

Comment: Yes, one of the PublishedEmployee.Id properties = 12 and the value entered into the function is also 12.

Comment: Are they both numbers? neither of them are strings?

Comment: `console.log(obj['PublishedEmployee.Id'], typeof obj['PublishedEmployee.Id'])`

Comment: you have to check against `obj.PublishedEmployee.Id` or obj['PublishedEmployee']['Id']

Comment: @koox00 when I update the code to check against your suggestion, I get console errors as follows: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of null, but $scope.shifts has 3 objects and only one of them has a null PublishedEmployee - the other two have numbers in the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking for the literal property "PublishedEmployee.Id" and not the sub property "Id" of "PublishedEmployee".

Change

```
if (obj['PublishedEmployee.Id'] === value && result === false)
```

to

```
if (!result && obj.PublishedEmployee && obj.PublishedEmployee.Id === value)
```

This will check for the existence of a `PublishedEmployee` property before attempting to compare its `Id` property.

---

If you're just wanting to check if any of the `$scope.shifts` match, you can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
return $scope.shifts.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.PublishedEmployee && obj.PublishedEmployee.Id === value;
});
```

Comment: So, the new code would look like this:

        $scope.checkSchedule = function (value) {
            var result = false;

            angular.forEach($scope.shifts, function (obj) {
                if (obj.PublishedEmployee.Id === value && result === false) {
                    result = true;
                }

            });
            return result;
        };

but that causes an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of null

Comment: @Flignats yes, I just saw that comment and have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That resolves the error, but still resolves to false. There is definitely a PublishedEmployee.Id = 12 and currentId = 12

Comment: @Flignats Oops, I've got no idea where I got "PublishingEmployee" from. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

In theory this will work if your data is as you say...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in shifts">
    <div ng-show="item.PublishedEmployee.Id == currentId">
        Matched
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using an ng-repeat in my HTML and instead use a foreach in the controller to resolve to a true statement so I can only use the ng-show.